# Can we capture the traffic of Desktop applications (not Web based applications) using Fiddler?

Tags: networking, jmeter, fiddler

**How can I record any traffic for a desktop based application in fiddler?**

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about **any** but you definitely can record HTTP and HTTPS traffic using Fiddler.

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fiddler_(software))

> Fiddler captures HTTP and HTTPS traffic and logs it for the user to review

If your application is using HTTP and/or HTTPS traffic you can even record it using JMeter's [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP(S)_Test_Script_Recorder), see [How to Run Performance Tests of Desktop Applications Using JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-run-performance-tests-desktop-applications-using-jmeter) article for details.

If your application is using different protocols you can use a lower level sniffer tool like [Wireshark](http://wireshark.org/)